# Spark session run but slaves won't run

Tags: ssh, pyspark

I am trying to understand how I can configure the Spark slaves.
I am running the master on a virtual machine ubuntu and it worked as I can run the shell with the command `pyspark` and I have access to the UI if I port forward when connecting to the VM.
My issue is when I add the master ip to the slave config file because if I start the slave by running `start-slaves.sh`, I got the following error (um1 is the name i gave to the VM ip address in `/etc/hosts`):

```
um1: ubuntu@um1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

From this I don't understand why it is looking for a publickey because the master is is also on the VM. Why does it try to connect? It should already be in ubuntu@um1. So I don't understand something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://blog.insightdatascience.com/simply-install-spark-cluster-mode-341843a52b88 follow this

Comment: how are slaves set up?

Comment: @thebluephantom I also use `um1` in the slave configuration file. So it is the public ip address. Should it be the private ip address?

Comment: not clear enuff for me on your setup.